# .NET Core 2.1.5 HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure on Deploy

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

deploying from VS version on the app service is: 2.1.403

and version on my local is: 2.1.403

here is a copy of the relevent section of the .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <UserSecretsId>952fa24f-1cbc-4017-8cdc-4b99e3671be7</UserSecretsId>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnBuildSuccess</RunPostBuildEvent>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <Content Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="NewFolder\**" />
    <None Remove="NewFolder\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bogus" Version="24.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="5.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I've tried:

1. using a self-contained deployment
2. specifying the version of the packages to 2.1.5 (though i've read this is not necessary)

my runtime.config in the build artifacts looks good:

```
    {
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "netcoreapp2.1",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.All",
      "version": "2.1.5"
    },
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

so what am I missing here?

Comment: I have seen the same error happen when there is problem with Startup code too. Can you enable the log and see if any exception is thrown (if there is no entry in Event Viewer).

Comment: Are using a client side frame work? Angular?

Comment: Run `dotnet YourApp.dll` on the server. If there's exceptions, fix the exceptions, or post them here if you need help fixing them. If it starts fine, then there's an issue with the hosting bundle installation on your server: either it is not installed or you neglected to restart your server after installing.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the issue:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All Version="2.1.1"/>
```

Though it could be a red herring as I have no idea why specifying the app version would fix (I thought the point of the shared framework was to dynamically pull in the versions you need.)

Also if it helps anyone: 2.1.5 is the release number and NOT THE VERSION OF THE SDK (it corresponds to 2.1.403)